# Is React Native Navigation v2 really stable?

Tags: react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

In the past, I have been using RNN v1 as part of a course and, also, as part of side projects.

Currently, I was wondering to try v2 so I grabbed my existing code and started translating it as per official documentation. However, I keep on getting failure Builds due to different files related to RNN. Many of them are documented as issues but some others are not being addressed.

Also, I have been looking at the react-native-navigation repository and have been looking that they are moving along subversions really fast so not sure whether that means that it is still not very stable.

So, what is your opinion? Shall I keep on using v1 or break my head trying to install v2?

Regards.

Alejandro.

Comment: It's a real pain right now. After weeks I still don't have parity with v1. Thought I had it, but turns out `passProps` in `showModal` doesn't work.